# Powershell command SCCM 2012 - Get all Resource Names from device collection?

Tags: powershell, scripting, sccm, system-center

I'm still learning about PowerShell and SCCM.

At the moment i'm trying to get all resource names of a device collection into an array variable. I don't know if this is possible?

Example:

```
Computers: Win7, Win8, CM02,....
```

into a variable like:

```
$computers = COMPUTERNAMEWIN7.local.domain.lo, COMPUTERNAMEWIN8.local.domain.lo, COMPUTERNAMECM02.local.domain.lo
```

This is what i'm trying to achieve:

I'm trying to deploy LibreOffice to all computers i have under my control in SCCM 2012.

So i have a Device Collection: "All Systems" with all these computers in it.

and then use a`Foreach-Object` command to copy and install the .Msi file of LibreOffice.

Is there a PowerShell command to get these into an array like the example, when specifying the device collection name ?

thank you :)

Comment: You understand the purpose of SCCM right? I'm curious why you aren't using SCCM to actually do the install?

Comment: @EBGreen is right, you can deploy the MSI using SCCM in less time than it took you to post this question. Look at the Software Library > Applications section.

Comment: Also, don't deploy anything to "All Systems" unless you really know what you are doing. All Systems includes the SCCM server and any other clients or servers that get added at any point in the future.

Comment: Technically the answer is something like (Get-CMCollectionMember -CollectionID SMS0001).Name but as the other guys mentioned the whole purpose of SCCM is to deploy software. It is also a lot easier because the account of your script would need to be admin on all those systems with full uac rights and you would have to account for all the offline systems. Also the source of libre office would have to be accessible for all systems. SCCM manages all this stuff for you